# ¿Cómo saber si un arreglo tiene huecos?

Tags: javascript

En javascript es fácil escribir un arreglo usando literales

```
var arreglo = [1, 2, 3];
```

Esto me creará un arreglo de tamaño 3 donde se puede iterar en todos sus elementos con un ciclo for

```
for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.lenght; i++) {
    console.log(arreglo[i]);
}
```

Pero hay un problema

Yo puedo declarar un arreglo de esta forma

```
var arreglo = new Array(3);
```

o hacer algo como esto

```
delete arreglo[1];
```

lo cual me creará un [sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) o arreglo con huecos

Ahora cuando voy a probar si el arreglo tiene un valor en esa posición puedo hacer algo como

```
for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.lenght; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i]) {
        // haz algo
    }
    // o también
    if (arreglo[i] !== undefined) {
        // haz algo
    }        
}
```

pero entonces si hago

```
arreglo[2] = undefined;
```

lo anterior fallará catastróficamente a pesar que el arreglo tiene un valor en esa posición

¿Cómo puedo detectar si en realidad hay un hueco o le han asignado el valor de `undefined` en esa posición?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si asignas

```
arreglo[2] = undefined;
```

para compara deberias usar

```
if(typeof arreglo[i] != 'undefined'){
   // haz algo
}
```

Para comparar el delete podrias usar

```
if(i in arreglo){
   // haz algo
}
```

[operador delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete)

valida el titulo `Eliminando elementos de un array`

Comment: Si le asigno cualquier otro valor esto no funcionará. Lo que quiero saber es si el arreglo tiene un hueco, no el tipo de datos que hay en esa posición

Comment: claro pero los huecos entendi lo puede resolver realizando el for por cada item, entendi que el problema era como comparaba ya sea que se use el delete o se asigne un undefined

Comment: Usar `delete` o asignar `undefined` no es lo mismo. La diferencia se nota cuando le haces `console.log` o `console.dir`. Yo quiero ser capaz de notar la diferencia.

Comment: Esta claro que no es lo mismo, ya que uno elimina la posicion del array, el otro solo asigna un valor indefinido. La diferencia la debes obtener realizando dos comparaciones distintas, con una sola no vas a poder lograrlo

Comment: Ahora sí. Usando el operador [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) me devuelve el resultado esperado en cada una de las comparaciones aunque lo haya creado con `new Array(length)`. Gracias

Comment: Para ECMAScript 5 en adelante simplemente puedes compar el `undefined` así: `arreglo[i] === undefined`

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz no se trata de saber si tiene un valor `undefined`. Es sobre saber si la posicion arreglo[i] tiene "algún valor". Si asigno `undefined` a esa posición la única forma de saber si es un hueco o una asignación es usando el operador `in` o usando el método `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: El comentario hace referencia al caso 1 que pone Leandro, la razón por la que compara el string `'undefined'` contra el `typeof(...)` es que comparar directamente contra `undefined` podía ser erroneo si es que por algún motivo se redefinía el undefined con otro valor. Esto ya no ocurre en ECMAScript 5. Mi comentario no tenía nada que ver el otro caso. Era solo una observación a esa línea de Leandro, no un intento de respuesta.